Are Comb diagrams an example of a universal construction?
Here is a bit about comb diagrams

This is taken from the following article:
Jacobs, Bart, Aleks Kissinger, and Fabio Zanasi. "Causal inference via string diagram surgery: A diagrammatic approach to interventions and counterfactuals." Mathematical Structures in Computer Science 31.5 (2021): 553-574.
Are these combs examples of universal constructions?

This question is better suited for MSE, but the short andwer is no; universal properties take the form ‘an $X$ with property $P$ such that for any $Y$ with property $P$ there exists a unique morphism $f:X\to Y$ (or $Y\to X$) such that property $P$ ‘factors’ through $f$’. This just a morphism that satisfies some coherence condition with some other morphism in the category.
